# Multiple Imputation - Help Needed

Tags: r, multiple-imputation, rms

These multiple imputation results relate to data I have previously described and shown here - [Skewed Distributions for Logistic Regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129739/skewed-distributions-for-logistic-regression)

Three variables I am using have missing data. Their names, descriptions and % missing are shown below.

```
inctoCran - Time from head injury to craniotomy in minutes = 0-2880 (After 2880 minutes is defined as a separate diagnosis) - 58% missing
GCS - Glasgow Coma Scale = 3-15 - 37% missing
rcteyemi - Pupil reactivity (1 = neither, 2 = one, 3 = both) - 56% missing
```

I have been using mutliple imputation to model the missing data above following advice in a previous post here - [Describing Results from Logistic Regression with Restricted Cubic Splines Using rms in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127134/describing-results-from-logistic-regression-with-restricted-cubic-splines-using)

Given this is a longitudinal analysis, a key variable of importance is the year of the treatment so we can investigate how our patient management has improved. The variable in question, `Yeardecimal` is highly significant in univariate analysis:

```
> rcs.ASDH<-lrm(formula = Survive ~ Yeardecimalc, data = ASDH_Paper1.1)
> 
> rcs.ASDH

Logistic Regression Model

lrm(formula = Survive ~ Yeardecimalc, data = ASDH_Paper1.1)

                      Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                         Ratio Test            Indexes          Indexes       
Obs          5998    LR chi2      91.47    R2       0.023    C       0.572    
 0           1281    d.f.             1    g        0.309    Dxy     0.143    
 1           4717    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    gr       1.362    gamma   0.146    
max |deriv| 3e-12                          gp       0.054    tau-a   0.048    
                                           Brier    0.165                     

             Coef   S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
Intercept    0.8696 0.0530 16.42  <0.0001 
Yeardecimalc 0.0551 0.0057  9.70  <0.0001
```

To deal with missingness, I used `aregImpute` and `fit.mult.impute` to conduct multiple imputation prior to multivariate logisic regression. When including Yeardecimal, the results were as follows:

```
> a <- aregImpute(~ I(Outcome30) + Age + GCS + I(Other) + ISS + inctoCran + I(rcteyemi) + I(neuroFirst) + I(neuroYN) + Mechanism + LOS + Yeardecimalc, nk=4, data = ASDH_Paper1.1, n.impute=10)
Iteration 13 
> 
> a

Multiple Imputation using Bootstrap and PMM

aregImpute(formula = ~I(Outcome30) + Age + GCS + I(Other) + ISS + 
    inctoCran + I(rcteyemi) + I(neuroFirst) + I(neuroYN) + Mechanism + 
    LOS + Yeardecimalc, data = ASDH_Paper1.1, n.impute = 10, 
    nk = 4)

n: 5998     p: 12   Imputations: 10     nk: 4 

Number of NAs:
   Outcome30          Age          GCS        Other          ISS    inctoCran     rcteyemi   neuroFirst      neuroYN 
           0            0         2242            0            0         3500         3376            0            0 
   Mechanism          LOS Yeardecimalc 
           0            0            0 

             type d.f.
Outcome30       c    1
Age             s    3
GCS             s    3
Other           c    1
ISS             s    3
inctoCran       s    3
rcteyemi        l    1
neuroFirst      l    1
neuroYN         l    1
Mechanism       c    4
LOS             s    3
Yeardecimalc    s    3

Transformation of Target Variables Forced to be Linear

R-squares for Predicting Non-Missing Values for Each Variable
Using Last Imputations of Predictors
      GCS inctoCran  rcteyemi 
    0.421     0.181     0.358 

> rcs.ASDH <- fit.mult.impute(Survive ~ rcs(Age) + GCS + Mechanism + rcs(ISS) + neuroFirst + rcs(inctoCrand) + inctoCranYN + rcs(Yeardecimalc) + Sex + Other + rcteyemi,lrm,a,data=ASDH_Paper1.1)

> rcs.ASDH

Logistic Regression Model

fit.mult.impute(formula = Survive ~ rcs(Age) + GCS + Mechanism + 
    rcs(ISS) + neuroFirst + rcs(inctoCrand) + inctoCranYN + rcs(Yeardecimalc) + 
    Sex + Other + rcteyemi, fitter = lrm, xtrans = a, data = ASDH_Paper1.1)

                      Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                         Ratio Test            Indexes          Indexes       
Obs          5998    LR chi2    1609.98    R2       0.365    C       0.836    
 0           1281    d.f.            25    g        1.584    Dxy     0.672    
 1           4717    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    gr       4.875    gamma   0.674    
max |deriv| 0.001                          gp       0.222    tau-a   0.226    
                                           Brier    0.121                     

                              Coef    S.E.    Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
Intercept                     21.3339 67.4400  0.32  0.7517  
Age                           -0.0088  0.0132 -0.67  0.5052  
Age'                          -0.0294  0.0643 -0.46  0.6471  
Age''                         -0.0134  0.2479 -0.05  0.9570  
Age'''                         0.2588  0.3534  0.73  0.4639  
GCS                            0.1100  0.0145  7.61  <0.0001 
Mechanism=Fall > 2m           -0.0651  0.1162 -0.56  0.5754  
Mechanism=Other                0.2285  0.1338  1.71  0.0876  
Mechanism=RTC                  0.0449  0.1332  0.34  0.7360  
Mechanism=Shooting / Stabbing  2.1150  1.1142  1.90  0.0577  
ISS                           -0.1069  0.0318 -3.36  0.0008  
ISS'                          -0.0359  0.1306 -0.27  0.7835  
ISS''                          1.8296  1.9259  0.95  0.3421  
neuroFirst                    -0.3483  0.0973 -3.58  0.0003  
inctoCrand                     0.0001  0.0053  0.02  0.9872  
inctoCrand'                   -0.0745  0.3060 -0.24  0.8077  
inctoCrand''                   0.1696  0.5901  0.29  0.7738  
inctoCrand'''                 -0.1167  0.3150 -0.37  0.7110  
inctoCranYN                   -0.2814  0.6165 -0.46  0.6480  
Yeardecimalc                  -0.0101  0.0337 -0.30  0.7641  
Yeardecimalc'                  0.0386  0.0651  0.59  0.5536  
Yeardecimalc''                -0.7417  0.8210 -0.90  0.3663  
Yeardecimalc'''                7.0367  4.9344  1.43  0.1539  
Sex=Male                       0.0668  0.0891  0.75  0.4534  
Other=1                        0.3238  0.1611  2.01  0.0445  
rcteyemi                       1.1589  0.1050 11.04  <0.0001 


> anova(rcs.ASDH)
                Wald Statistics          Response: Survive 

 Factor          Chi-Square d.f. P     
 Age              83.07      4   <.0001
  Nonlinear        5.97      3   0.1131
 GCS              57.89      1   <.0001
 Mechanism         8.14      4   0.0867
 ISS              77.31      3   <.0001
  Nonlinear       35.04      2   <.0001
 neuroFirst       12.81      1   0.0003
 inctoCrand        2.32      4   0.6777
  Nonlinear        2.29      3   0.5149
 inctoCranYN       0.21      1   0.6480
 Yeardecimalc      4.19      4   0.3807
  Nonlinear        3.77      3   0.2874
 Sex               0.56      1   0.4534
 Other             4.04      1   0.0445
 rcteyemi        121.80      1   <.0001
 TOTAL NONLINEAR  47.27     11   <.0001
 TOTAL           679.09     25   <.0001
>
```

Yeardecimal is no longer significant. However, if I exclude Yeardecimal from aregImpute only, I have the alternative result below:

```
> a <- aregImpute(~ I(Outcome30) + Age + GCS + I(Other) + ISS + inctoCran + I(rcteyemi) + I(neuroFirst) + I(neuroYN) + Mechanism + LOS, nk=4, data = ASDH_Paper1.1, n.impute=10)
Iteration 13 
> 
> a

Multiple Imputation using Bootstrap and PMM

aregImpute(formula = ~I(Outcome30) + Age + GCS + I(Other) + ISS + 
    inctoCran + I(rcteyemi) + I(neuroFirst) + I(neuroYN) + Mechanism + 
    LOS, data = ASDH_Paper1.1, n.impute = 10, nk = 4)

n: 5998     p: 11   Imputations: 10     nk: 4 

Number of NAs:
 Outcome30        Age        GCS      Other        ISS  inctoCran   rcteyemi neuroFirst    neuroYN  Mechanism        LOS 
         0          0       2242          0          0       3500       3376          0          0          0          0 

           type d.f.
Outcome30     c    1
Age           s    3
GCS           s    3
Other         c    1
ISS           s    3
inctoCran     s    3
rcteyemi      l    1
neuroFirst    l    1
neuroYN       l    1
Mechanism     c    4
LOS           s    3

Transformation of Target Variables Forced to be Linear

R-squares for Predicting Non-Missing Values for Each Variable
Using Last Imputations of Predictors
      GCS inctoCran  rcteyemi 
    0.407     0.194     0.320 
> 

> rcs.ASDH <- fit.mult.impute(Survive ~ rcs(Age) + GCS + Mechanism + rcs(ISS) + neuroFirst + rcs(inctoCrand) + inctoCranYN + rcs(Yeardecimalc) + Sex + Other + rcteyemi,lrm,a,data=ASDH_Paper1.1)
> rcs.ASDH

Logistic Regression Model

fit.mult.impute(formula = Survive ~ rcs(Age) + GCS + Mechanism + 
    rcs(ISS) + neuroFirst + rcs(inctoCrand) + inctoCranYN + rcs(Yeardecimalc) + 
    Sex + Other + rcteyemi, fitter = lrm, xtrans = a, data = ASDH_Paper1.1)

                      Model Likelihood     Discrimination    Rank Discrim.    
                         Ratio Test            Indexes          Indexes       
Obs          5998    LR chi2    1607.92    R2       0.364    C       0.834    
 0           1281    d.f.            25    g        1.578    Dxy     0.667    
 1           4717    Pr(> chi2) <0.0001    gr       4.846    gamma   0.669    
max |deriv| 0.003                          gp       0.221    tau-a   0.224    
                                           Brier    0.120                     

                              Coef     S.E.    Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
Intercept                     -55.6574 58.3464 -0.95  0.3401  
Age                            -0.0084  0.0128 -0.66  0.5105  
Age'                           -0.0335  0.0612 -0.55  0.5838  
Age''                           0.0050  0.2365  0.02  0.9830  
Age'''                          0.2321  0.3387  0.69  0.4930  
GCS                             0.1099  0.0124  8.88  <0.0001 
Mechanism=Fall > 2m            -0.0631  0.1138 -0.55  0.5793  
Mechanism=Other                 0.2354  0.1381  1.70  0.0883  
Mechanism=RTC                   0.0315  0.1319  0.24  0.8114  
Mechanism=Shooting / Stabbing   1.9297  1.0930  1.77  0.0775  
ISS                            -0.1012  0.0335 -3.02  0.0025  
ISS'                           -0.0599  0.1366 -0.44  0.6613  
ISS''                           2.1581  2.0120  1.07  0.2834  
neuroFirst                     -0.3753  0.0888 -4.23  <0.0001 
inctoCrand                     -0.0007  0.0054 -0.13  0.9002  
inctoCrand'                    -0.0496  0.3116 -0.16  0.8734  
inctoCrand''                    0.1316  0.6021  0.22  0.8270  
inctoCrand'''                  -0.1078  0.3224 -0.33  0.7381  
inctoCranYN                    -0.1697  0.6172 -0.27  0.7834  
Yeardecimalc                    0.0281  0.0291  0.96  0.3349  
Yeardecimalc'                   0.0682  0.0600  1.14  0.2553  
Yeardecimalc''                 -1.4037  0.7685 -1.83  0.0678  
Yeardecimalc'''                10.2513  4.8156  2.13  0.0333  
Sex=Male                        0.0595  0.0890  0.67  0.5037  
Other=1                         0.3579  0.1641  2.18  0.0292  
rcteyemi                        1.1862  0.0799 14.85  <0.0001 


> anova(rcs.ASDH)
                Wald Statistics          Response: Survive 

 Factor          Chi-Square d.f. P     
 Age              78.39      4   <.0001
  Nonlinear        6.23      3   0.1011
 GCS              78.86      1   <.0001
 Mechanism         7.53      4   0.1104
 ISS              76.46      3   <.0001
  Nonlinear       31.16      2   <.0001
 neuroFirst       17.87      1   <.0001
 inctoCrand        3.22      4   0.5214
  Nonlinear        3.19      3   0.3630
 inctoCranYN       0.08      1   0.7834
 Yeardecimalc     44.83      4   <.0001
  Nonlinear        4.67      3   0.1979
 Sex               0.45      1   0.5037
 Other             4.76      1   0.0292
 rcteyemi        220.51      1   <.0001
 TOTAL NONLINEAR  45.39     11   <.0001
 TOTAL           715.22     25   <.0001
>
```

Can anyone help me understand why the statistical results for Yeardecimal are so starkly different?

Comment: I can't answer your direct question. However, I suggest you to consider trying to reproduce your analysis, using `mice` for multiple imputation. See my [earlier answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/129630/31372), especially pay attention to the mentioned sections in the referenced paper.